# Copy data randomly from one file and paste it randomly in other Excel using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pull a file-(1) inside a excel file(2) by browsing in my computer. And pull data from the file-(1) from different cells randomly and paste it in file(2).
I am beginner and trying to copy bits and parts from different program to make it work.I have complied a code that works okay.

I face some problem.
a) As I am copying and pasting each cell one by one the program is too long and my screen flashes white many times. (I tried Application.EnableEvents = False  but it didn't work. May be I don't know where to insert it exactly)

b) can it be done once I copy the data from file(1) Inside file(2), Can the file(1) be closed(or loose from browse link).

c)can the code be made short ? (like copying together and pasting together etc).I have to copy data from 10 more cells.

```
Sub PullData()
Dim uploadfile As Variant
Dim uploader As Workbook
Dim CurrentBook As Workbook

Set CurrentBook = ActiveWorkbook
MsgBox ("Please select uploader file to be reviewed")
uploadfile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
If uploadfile = "False" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open uploadfile
Set uploader = ActiveWorkbook
With uploader
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("L10").Copy
End With
CurrentBook.Activate
Sheets("Calculations").Range("AO29").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Workbooks.Open uploadfile
Set uploader = ActiveWorkbook
With uploader
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("L11").Copy
End With
CurrentBook.Activate
Sheets("Calculations").Range("AO26").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Workbooks.Open uploadfile
Set uploader = ActiveWorkbook
With uploader
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("H24").Copy
End With
CurrentBook.Activate
Sheets("Calculations").Range("AO13").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Workbooks.Open uploadfile
Set uploader = ActiveWorkbook
With uploader
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("H27").Copy
End With
CurrentBook.Activate
Sheets("Calculations").Range("AO18").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


Workbooks.Open uploadfile
Set uploader = ActiveWorkbook
With uploader
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("H26").Copy
End With
CurrentBook.Activate
Sheets("Calculations").Range("AO17").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Workbooks.Open uploadfile
Set uploader = ActiveWorkbook
With uploader
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("L9").Copy
End With
CurrentBook.Activate
Sheets("Calculations").Range("AO25").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Workbooks.Open uploadfile
Set uploader = ActiveWorkbook
With uploader
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("E42").Copy
End With
CurrentBook.Activate
Sheets("Calculations").Range("AO34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Workbooks.Open uploadfile
Set uploader = ActiveWorkbook
With uploader
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("E43").Copy
End With
CurrentBook.Activate
Sheets("Calculations").Range("AO33").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Workbooks.Open uploadfile
Set uploader = ActiveWorkbook
With uploader
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("E48").Copy
End With
CurrentBook.Activate
Sheets("Calculations").Range("AO45").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Workbooks.Open uploadfile
Set uploader = ActiveWorkbook
With uploader
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("E50").Copy
End With
CurrentBook.Activate
Sheets("Calculations").Range("AO44").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Application.screenupdating = False` and yes, you can set ranges to each other instead of copy/pasting.

Comment: Also, to use the `With` statement change `Range...` to `.Worksheets("WorksheetName").Range...` The `With` statement removes the need to retype objects.

Comment: @ findwindow thanks for the help 
I tried Application.screenupdating  =  false in the beginning before copying starts.  and Application.screenupdating  = True before End Sub. but it doesn't work. Screen keeps flashing. Do I have to write it before every copy?
@Brian thank you for the help
is it possible to write a small example code for me, copying two cell and pasting it. I can try to make it work from there. I am not from coding background and my coding literacy is 1/10. I couldn't understand what does the comment mean.

Comment: @Eric - the screen keeps flashing because you keep opening the same workbook, then activating and selecting multiple workbooks. See my answer below for an clean and working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you a lot:

```
Sub PullData()

Dim uploadfile As Variant
Dim uploader As Workbook
Dim CurrentBook As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set CurrentBook = ThisWorkbook 'refers to workbook with code

MsgBox ("Please select uploader file to be reviewed")

uploadfile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

If uploadfile = "False" Then Exit Sub

Set uploader = Workbooks.Open(uploadfile) 'stay away from ActiveWorkbook AMAP

With CurrentBook.Sheets("Calculations")
    .Range("AO29").Value = uploader.Sheets(1).Range("L10").Value
    .Range("AO26").Value = uploader.Sheets(1).Range("L11").Value
    .Range("AO13").Value = uploader.Sheets(1).Range("H24").Value
    'add the rest of your references here
End With 

uploader.close savechanges:=false

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you scott. 
Somehow I got error in line -    
    set uploader = workbook.open uploadfile   .

Comment: @Eric - fixed it. Sorry. Forgot the parenthesis when setting the object.

Comment: Great it worked at that part. 
But now it is show error in copy and paste line.
The file(1)has  6 tabs/sheets, that is opened in sheet 1 of file(2)  and pulling the value in "calculations" which is 2nd tab of file(2).  is that error coming due to 6 tabs in the file?

Comment: @Eric - you can change the `Sheets(1)` reference to `Sheets("mySheetName")` to be more specific in pulling from the *exact* sheet from the `uploader` workbook. I used `Sheets(1)` since you didn't specify in your code which sheet, so I assumed it only had one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simplified version of what you're doing, that actually picks random cells every time.

```
Sub PullData()

Dim lngCount As Long
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngSrcRow As Long
Dim lngSrcCol As Long

Dim uploadfile As Variant
Dim uploader As Workbook
Dim CurrentBook As Workbook

Set CurrentBook = ActiveWorkbook
MsgBox ("Please select uploader file to be reviewed")
uploadfile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
If uploadfile = "False" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set uploader = Workbooks.Open uploadfile
For lngCount = 1 To 10
    Do While True
        lngRow = Abs(lngRow + Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(-5, 10))
        If lngRow = 0 Then lngRow = lngRow + 1
        If IsEmpty(CurrentBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lngRow)) Then Exit Do
    Loop
    lngSrcRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    lngSrcCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count)
    CurrentBook.Worksheets("Calculations").Range("AO" & lngRow).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(lngSrcRow, lngSrcCol).Value
Next lngCount

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
uploader.close savechanges:=false
End Sub
```